# VueX with TypeScript array .push is not a function

Tags: typescript, vuex

I've created a VueX store file which looks likes this:

```
// Import packages
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist';

// Import models
import Problem from './models/Problem';

// Create localStorage persistence object
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence<RootState>({
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    problems: Array<Problem>(),
  },

  mutations: {
    addProblem(state: any, problem: Problem) {
      state.problems.push(problem);
    },
    setProblems(state: any, problems: Array<Problem>) {
      state.problems = problems;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    addProblem(context: any, problem: Problem) {
      context.commit('addProblem', problem);
    },
    setProblems(context: any, problems: Array<Problem>) {
      context.commit('setProblems', problems);
    },
  },

  plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
});
```

But when I try to use the `addProblem` action the console returns this error

> TypeError: state.problems.push is not a function

I don't understand why though since I've initiated the array properly (I think?) and when I lookup a tutorial such as [this](https://medium.com/@RupaniChirag/vuex-with-typescript-b83a62aa48a8) one, they seem to be able to use `push` just fine.

Comment: Initialise the problems state to an empty array. Something like  `state: { problems: [],}. I want to test a theory.

Comment: Still results in the same problem @Tony

Comment: This error usually results when the state in question (in this case, `state.problems`) does not return an array. Check vue devtools to confirm that it returns an array.

Comment: Ahh you're right, it does indeed just show a number @Tony :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I was using persistent storage since I was using persistent storage I had set the array to a number before. Every time I reloaded the page it would just return to this number.

**The solution was just resetting local storage!**

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push` has a return type of `number` (the new length of the array). Therefore the following line in your code causes `problems` to become a number and not an array:

```
      state.problems = state.problems.push(problem);
```

Comment: A bit off topic but that is the reason typescript dont want you to use `any` like here in `state: any`.

Comment: I've changed the push function but it still returns the same error, as per your comment if I remove the any it still results in the same error but VS code just complains about it so how should I handle that?

Comment: Any changes to the typing system of typescript will not result in any change during runtime. It is explicitly for checking your times during compile time, therefore you don't see any change. You should workout whatever is noted by your IDE to solve the problem.

Hint: problems is undefined / not an array